# JS While loop ignoring And condition?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code to find [Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), why am I getting duplicates rather than excluding them with the While loop followed by the If condition?

```js
var a, b, c, i, pyTrips, temp;
pyTrips = new Array();
temp = new Array();

for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
        with (Math) {
            c = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2));
        }
        if (c % 1 == 0) {
            temp = a < b ? [a, b, c] : [b, a, c];
            i = 0;
            while (i < pyTrips.length && pyTrips[i] !== temp) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i === pyTrips.length) {
                pyTrips.push(temp);
            }
            console.log(pyTrips.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I assume it's the `pyTrips[i]!==temp` part that's tripping things up, but I've checked and there's no type casting or anything; the comparison is in fact between two arrays. So not sure why the While loop seems to make it to `pyTrips.length` every time.

Comment: `[1] !== [1]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript), or any of the many other questions about object and array equality. Also, there's no need for `with`, which isn't available in strict mode and is dangerous (you can do `const { pow, sqrt } = Math` if you want to use those functions the same way).

Comment: Thanks for the link: it's very hard to track down these answers when they involve such generic terms (read as: mostly irrelevant results). I'm using this script locally to just dump info: it will never be run in strict mode. And I'm using With just to clean up the line's readability, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, you cannot compare two arrays directly. When you compare two arrays using the === operator, it compares their references, not their content.

One hacky way to solve this is to use `toString()`, convert the two arrays to string and then compare

```js
pyTrips[i].toString() !== temp.toString()
```

Another way is to use a utility function which compares arrays

```js
const isEqualArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    return arr1.every((ele, index) => ele === arr2[index]);
};
```

And then use it like

```js
!isEqualArr(pyTrips[i], temp)
```

Comment: Am I really supposed to format my code on _Stack_ the way you changed it? I can deal with the extra whitespace, but I hate to put statements containing only a single line on multiple lines.

Comment: I just used an online prettifier, https://prettier.io/playground/#. In my humble opinion, it improves readability.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript arrays are objects.  Objects are compared by comparing their object references, NOT by comparing their contents.

You can do this by using `toString` on both arrays:

```
while(i<pyTrips.length && pyTrips[i].toString()!==temp.toString()){ i++; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the array after each successful iteration:

```
var a, b, c, i, pyTrips, temp;
pyTrips = new Array();
temp = new Array();

for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
        with (Math) {
            c = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2));
        }
        if (c % 1 == 0) {
            temp = a < b ? [a, b, c] : [b, a, c];
            i = 0;
            while (i < pyTrips.length && pyTrips[i] !== temp) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i === pyTrips.length) {
                pyTrips.push(temp);
            }
            console.log(pyTrips.toString());
            pyTrips = [];
        }
    }
}
```